# PHP echo value from JSON into Javascript code gives error

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to decode a JSON file to display the data in Google Maps. This works perfectly, but the JSON file consists partly of data generated by users and includes usernames and description text. This often include characters like `'`, `?`, `"`, `\`, `_`, `.`, and so on.

This is no problem when I echo the data as a simple HTML list. But when I echo the data as Javascript to be displayed on Google Maps, the special characters give me errors, especially `\n`.

I have tried serializing the data of the JSON file. I have tried `htmlspecialcharacters` and `addslashes` but nothing seems to work. What else can I try?

Snippet from JSON-sourcefile giving error;

```
"reportDescription":"linke Spur gesperrt\nnur eine Spur befahrbar"
```

Result with `var_dump` after `json_decode`;

```
["reportDescription"]=> string(43) "linke Spur gesperrt nur eine Spur befahrbar"
```

Result with `addslashes(htmlspecialchars($feature['reportDescription']))` after `json_decode` and simple PHP `echo` function;

```
1877 - linke Spur gesperrt nur eine Spur befahrbar  -
```

Echoed with additional Javascript code according to Javascript Google Maps API v3;

```
var alert1877_content =  '<div id="alert1877_content">'+
'<b>linke Spur gesperrt
nur eine Spur befahrbar</b></br>'+
```

As you can see the `\n` results in a breakline in the code.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Why aren't you just passing the JSON directly as JSON to your Javascript? Why decode it in PHP just to put it (incorrectly) back into Javascript?

Comment: I guess because I thought it was the only way... And to prevent third parties to see the JSON source... Thanks for the new direction. I'm off exploring!